# Include and use libpng to C program using CMake [Windows]

Tags: c, windows, cmake, zlib, libpng

Hi im trying to include libpng in my C program using CMake (p.s im new to CMake). I want to use it to generate png of the qrcode generated by libqrencode. What I have done so far:

### 1. Install zlib from [zlib](http://zlib.net)

```
// extract to zlib
cd zlib
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\zlib -S . -B out/build/
cmake --build out/build --target INSTALL --config Release
```

### 2. Install libpng from [libpng 1637](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/)

```
// extract to libpng
cd libpng
cmake -S . -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/zlib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/libpng -B out/build/
cmake --build out/build --target INSTALL --config Release
```

### 3. Install libqrencode from [libqrencode](https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode)

```
cd libqrencode-master
// configure
cmake  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/qrencode-fukuchi -DWITH_TOOLS=NO 
       -DZLIB_LIBRARY=C:/zlib/bin -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR=C:/zlib/include 
       -DPNG_LIBRARY=C:/libpng/bin -DPNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR=C:/libpng/include 
       -DICONV_LIBRARY=C:/libiconv/bin -DICONV_INCLUDE_DIR=C:/libiconv/include 
           -S . -B out/build
// install
cmake --build out/build --target INSTALL --config Release
```

Now i create my c program to call libpng and libqrencode using CMakeLists

```
│   CMakeLists.txt
│   main.c
│
└───out
    └───build
```

The CMakesLists content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23.0)
project(QR)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
                            PUBLIC C:/qrencode-fukuchi/include
                            PUBLIC C:/libpng/include)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
                            C:/qrencode-fukuchi/lib/qrencode.lib
                            C:/libpng/lib/libpng16.lib)
```

The main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "qrencode.h"
#include "png.h"

enum imageType {
    PNG_TYPE,
    PNG32_TYPE,
};
static enum imageType image_type = PNG_TYPE;

int main(){

    printf("hello fukuchi\n");
    
    char*           szSourceSring = "Helloo";
    QRcode*         pQRC;
    char*           outfile = "test.png";

    // Compute QRCode
    pQRC = QRcode_encodeString(szSourceSring, 0, QR_ECLEVEL_H, QR_MODE_8, 1);
    writePNG(pQRC, outfile, image_type);
    QRcode_free(pQRC);
    printf("bye fukuchi\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then i configure and build:

```
cmake -S . -B out/build
cmake --build out/build
```

I found no problem so far but when i call the exe file:

```
.\out\build\Debug\QR
```

It just terminates instantly with no error code. But when i commented the `writePNG(pQRC, outfile, image_type)` and reconfigure and build it again now it show:

```
hello fukuchi
bye fukuchi
```

### Update 1:

I updated my CMakelists.txt of the main.c like this (added zlib lib and reorder the linking libraries) and managed the executables to compile and executed properly when the `writePNG` function is called

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23.0)
project(QR)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
                            PUBLIC C:/qrencode-fukuchi/include 
                            PUBLIC C:/libpng/include)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
                            C:/zlib/lib/zlib.lib
                            C:/libpng/lib/libpng16.lib
                            C:/qrencode-fukuchi/lib/qrencode.lib)

#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} C:/libpng/lib/libpng16.lib)
```

But now my `writePNG` function causing debug assertion problem

```
crtlsValidHeapPointer(block)
is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)
HEAP_CORRECTION_DETECTED
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory before start of the heap
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of the heap
```

The assertion occurs when it hit this line:

```
png_write_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);
```

The full writePNG function can be viewed here: [code](https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode/blob/master/qrenc.c#L292)

Please help me